# MySQL select and in where and return two values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a two tables, one table has prices, the second table has a priceRangeId, priceRangeMin, priceRangeMax. What I am trying to do is take a priceRangeId and search the first table with the prices that in between the priceRangeMax and PriceRangeMin in my where clause, is this possible?

heres what I got:

```
$priceRangeId = 1;

SELECT * 
FROM `table1` 
WHERE price BETWEEN (
    SELECT * FROM `table2` 
    WHERE priceRangeId IN (" . $priceRangeId . ") 
    ORDER BY `priceRangeMin`
);
```

but I get this error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax`

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If memory serves, `BETWEEN` expects two arguments, and you're supplying one and expecting it to auto-magically determine what needs to be done.

Comment: as Moo-Juice pointed out, between expects two arguments, like "price between 5 and 10",  what is the "*" in table two? Even if they were two different numerical values, the query interpreter cannot be expected to understand and place appropriately the columns.  Additionally, from the looks of your inner query, you'd be getting potentially multiple rows returned from your inner query

Comment: `BETWEEN foo AND bar`, not `BETWEEN foo` like you're doing. You cannot use the results of a subquery as the filter clauses in your between anyways, even if that subquery was returning two fields/values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `table1`
WHERE price BETWEEN
(SELECT priceRangeMin FROM `table2`
        WHERE priceRangeId='$priceRangeId') as min_price
AND (SELECT priceRangeMax FROM `table2`
        WHERE priceRangeId='$priceRangeId') as max_price
```

Comment: Is there a reason we'd prefer two subqueries to a simple JOIN operation?

Comment: Actually, this logic came first in my mind. we can do it with `JOIN` too.

Comment: this gives me an error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as min_price AND (SELECT rb_priceRangeMax FROM rb_priceRange WHERE rb_priceRange' at line 5

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT table1.* 
  FROM table1, table2
 WHERE table2.priceRangeId = $priceRangeId
   AND table1.price between table2.PriceRangeMin AND table2.PriceRangeMax
;
```

Comment: Is there a reason we'd prefer the old-school comma syntax for a join operation, rather than the newer style `JOIN` keyword?